# java String regex pattern match and replace string

Tags: java, regex, string

There is a string, if that pattern matches need to return first few char's only.

```
String str = "PM 17/PM 19 - Test String";
```

expecting return string --> `PM 17`

Here my String pattern checking for:

1) always starts with **PM**
2) then followed by space (or some time zero space)
3) then followed by some number
4) then followed by slash (i.e. /)
5) then followed by Same string **PM**
6) then followed by space (or some time zero space)
7) Then followed by number
8) then any other chars/strings.

If given string matches above pattern, I need to get string till before the slash (i.e. **PM 17**)

I tried below way but it did not works for the condition.

```
  if(str.matches("PM\\s+[0-9.]/PM(.*)")) { //"PM//s+[0-9]/PM(.*)"
                  str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("/"));
                  flag = true;
  }
```

Comment: `PM` appears nowhere in your regex. Did you see that?

Comment: corrected it with PM.

Comment: next issue: `[0-9]` matches one digit, not multiple such as `17`.

Comment: `//s+` means "two forward slashes, literal `s` character repeated 1 to infinity times". You probably meant `\\s+`

Comment: try `^PM\s*\d{2}`

Comment: updated to [0-9.] to get any numbers. and updated to \\s+

Comment: @bubbles how exactly? I am getting compile error for that ^PM\s*\d{2}

Comment: @mgr in java you have to double the slash sorry, it will be "^PM\\s*\\d{2}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.matches` you may use `.replaceFirst` here with a *capturing group*:

```
str = str.replaceFirst( "^(PM\\s*\\d+)/PM\\s*\\d+.*$", "$1" );
//=> PM 17
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3plWgY/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Line start
- `(PM\\s*\\d+)`: Match and group text starting with `PM` followed by 0 or more whitespace followed by 1 or more digits
- `/PM\\s*\\d+`: Match `/PM` followed by 0 or more whitespace followed by 1 or more digits
- `.*$`: Match any # of characters before line end
- `$1`: is **replacement** that puts captured string of first group back in the replacement.

---

If you want to do input validation before substring extraction then I suggest this code:

```
final String regex = "(PM\\s*\\d+)/PM\\s*\\d+.*";    
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    flag = true;
    str = matcher.group(1);
}
```